# Is there a way to pass arbitrary text to Vim?

Tags: vim

I want a way to pass some literal text to Vim.  I've seen that it can [read from stdin](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/usr_26.html) with the "-" argument, so you can pipe things to it, e.g. the output of other commands.

But is there a way to pass **any** text into it like

```
vim - "Here's some random text"
```

and open Vim with that string in the buffer?

It complains if I try this command...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$ echo "Here's some random text" | vim -
```

Answer (score 6):

```
echo string | vim -
```

Comment: + in `bash` one can do a `vim - <<<$string`

Answer (score 0):

```
cat some_file | vim -
```

This is the correct way to pipe into vim.

Comment: Except that the OP was asking how to pipe a literal string in, not the contents of a file.